# multiply and add to vector of integer

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, stdvector

Write a program which prompts the user to enter data into  a vector of integers and assigns to another vector of integers the values of the first vector (modified by multiplying by 8 and incremented by 100) BUT IN REVERSE ORDER.
Example:
We enter into the first vector the values:

```
3   8   2   9   11  5  40 100 203 49
```

Then the second vector has the values:

```
(49*8 +100) (203*8 +100) (100*8 +100) (40*8 +100) (5*8 +100) (11*8 +100) (9*8 +100)
(2*8 +100) (8*8 +100) (3*8 +100) .
```

So this is the question being asked but yet all I can do in my code so far is input the integers and reverse order them but I can't figure out how to add the math into the coding.(adding 100 and times 8)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int input[500], output[500], count, i;

    cout << "Enter number of elements in array\n";
    cin >> count;

    cout << "Enter " << count << " numbers \n";

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        cin >> input[i];
    }

    // Copy numbers from inputArray to outputArray in 
    // reverse order 
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        output[i] = input[count-i-1];
    }    

    cout << "Reversed Array\n";
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        cout << output[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SImply output[i]=8*input[...] + 100. Check cout <= 100. Use vector.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have not used the `std::vector<int>` anywhere in your code, rather, you have normal arrays with both of them with size `500`. This was not the requirement.

Read about [std::vector<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and use them instead of those arrays, by *allocating the size* only what the user wants to have.(i.e, accordingly the user input `count`).

Secondly, you could have done the calculations to each of the elements in `input` vector while you copying/ filling to `output` vector array.

Here is an example code: <kbd>[DEMO HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IwfvSoVx3KqsHn17)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter number of elements in array\n";
    std::size_t count; std::cin >> count;

    std::cout << "Enter " << count << " numbers \n";
    std::vector<int> input(count, 0);
    // input element
    for (int& element : input) std::cin >> element;

    std::vector<int> output; output.reserve(count); // reserve memory for elements

    // apply to the output vector: for that    
    // simply reverse iterate input array using the while loop, 
    // emplace back the calculated result to the output array
    while (count--)
    {
        output.emplace_back((input[count] * 8) + 100);
    }

    // print out the output
    std::cout << "Reversed Array\n";
    for (const int element : output)    std::cout << element << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Enter number of elements in array
10
Enter 10 numbers
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Reversed Array
180 172 164 156 148 140 132 124 116 108
```

---

That being said, you could have also done it by std algorithm function **[`std::trasform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)**. For that, [iterate reversely](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) the `input`  vector in `std::transform` and using a *lambda function*(which calculate the necessary), and [insert back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to the vector `output`.

<kbd>[SEE LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Atdcpddsj6Ivisbi)</kbd>

```
#include <algorithm> // std::transform

auto doMath = [](int element) { return (element * 8) + 100; }; // lambda which does the calculation
std::transform(input.crbegin(), input.crend(), std::back_inserter(output), doMath);
```

---

or you can even trick the user by **having only one vector array** throughout the program where you will store **user inputs directly after making the calculation** like follows:

<kbd>[SEE LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7YDLvlDqH7Kvt7ed)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::size_t count; std::cin >> count;
    std::vector<int> vec; vec.reserve(count);
    // take the input and store the calculated value directly in the vec array
    while (count--)
    {
        int element; std::cin >> element;
        vec.emplace_back((element * 8) + 100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how will I add this code into the code I have above??

Comment: @AlexMesillas Actually your given task and the code you have written does not match. You have used an not mal arrays `input[500], output[500]` which had to be using [std::vector<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: with the code above I was trying to run it and see how it works but it only lets me go up to 4 numbers instead of 10?

Comment: @AlexMesillas the first input is count. You would have given it 4. That is why you could only 4 inputs. To distinguish the input, you may provide a debug message. See my updated answer and the links.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy the numbers from inputArray to outputArray in reverse order, you basically access to each and every element of inputArray and then put them in to the new array, so you can also change them in this step too:

```
//take the element index (count - 1 - i) from inputArray, 
//multiply by 8, then increment by 100, 
//then assign output element index i equal to the result 

cout << "Reversed Array\n";
for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    output[i] = ((input[count-i-1]) * 8) + 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual calculation is a one-liner:

```
std::vector<int> input(count);
// populate input vector here...
std::vector<int> result(count);

// one-liner, formatted for easier readability
std::transform(std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input),
    std::rbegin(result),
    [](int incoming) { return 8 * incoming + 100; } );
```

The calls to `std::cbegin` and `std::cend` return iterators that point at the first element of `input` and past-the-end of `input`, respectively.

The call to `std::rbegin` returns a **reverse** iterator into `result`; it runs from the end of the vector back toward the beginning.

That last line is a **lambda function** -- it gets called with an `int` argument named `incoming` and returns the calculated value.

The standard algorithm `std::transform` runs through the input range (`std::cbegin(input) .. std::cend(input)`) and for each element, applies the lambda function and stores the result in the output range (`std::rbegin(output)`; no end iterator, because the algorithm terminates when the input range has been exhausted).

That looks more complicated than the one-off solutions in other answers. But once you get used to using iterators and algorithms, this becomes a natural formulation, with the advantage of greater clarity and flexibility. For example, if your requirements changed and you needed to write the values in order instead of reverse order, you'd just change `std::rbegin(result)` to `std::begin(result)`.